# I got this error /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: undefined symbol: ap_accept_lock_mech

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I got this error while restarting the apache server.

> /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: undefined symbol: ap_accept_lock_mech

Comment: You compiled mod_wsgi module is not compatible with the Apache version you are running. Ensure you are using most up to date versions and if mod_wsgi was compiled from source code, recompile it and reinstall it for your current Apache version.

Comment: I am using apache 2.4 with mod_wsgi version 4.4.21. Thanks for your advise. I will check it.

Comment: I compile it with mod_wsgi  4.5.13, again its showing the same error..

Comment: Can you please help me.. I used python 2.7 with mod_wsgi 4.5.3 and apache 2.4. But its showing the same error.

Comment: You have the incorrect -dev or -devel package for Apache installed then. That is, the headers files in the dev package aren't for the same Apache version as runtime has. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using CentOS release 6.8 (Final). WHM cPanel server

Comment: Have you tried ensuring you have latest ``httpd`` and ``httpd-devel`` packages?

Comment: ea-apache24-devel-2.4.25-2.2.1.cpanel.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: Where is the ``httpd`` or ``apache2`` binary that cPanel package installs? If it is in a separare tree, is ``apxs`` or ``apxs2`` also install in that tree? Where else is ``apxs`` installed on your system?